# php pdo function connect to DB and do query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to be as efficient with code as possible. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out a good way of doing this. I have tried using Sammitch's code which does look cleaner but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

I would like a way to stop having to use prepare, execute, every time and a function to me makes the most sense. Using Simmitch's suggestion, I removed the initial connection to database to stop unnecessary overheads but the code still does not work. Showing a "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined" error.

My code at present (some parts omitted as not necessary):

```
/*Function to talk to database*/
function doQuery($myDB, $myQuery, $myValues)
{
    try
    {     
        $st = $myDB->prepare($myQuery);       
        $st->execute($myValues);
        //echo $success;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Failed because: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='dbanme';charset=utf8', 'dbuser', 'dbpass');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); //Set error mode
    $query = "INSERT INTO users(login,pass,email,county) VALUES(:username,:password,:email,:count)";
    $values = array('username' => $_POST['username'],
                     'password' => $_POST['password1'],
                     'email' => $_POST['email'],
                     'county' => $_POST['county']
                     );
    doQuery($db, $query, $values);
```

Comment: how do I format it? I can never understand how this works. I wish I could just use bbcode on this site! ;'(

Comment: Get yourself a copy of [**Notepad++**](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (it's free btw) paste your code inside a new file, "select all CTRL-A" then press the TAB key. Then, do select all again, then copy/re-paste in your question. It's as easy as 1-2-3 ;-) (this will prove to be useful in more ways than one)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Notepad++ is system specific. The StackOverflow code editor's `{}` button usually fixes things.

Comment: Seems like `relentless` did it for you. You can give "thanks" for that ;-)

Comment: I use dreamweaver, I just didn't know it had to be tabbed for it to work. I had re-edited it. I think some mod was editing it too but I removed a lot of the useless code as it wasn't of any use really.

Comment: @tadman I've never used the `{}`. There are certain things I am not aware of on SO, strangely enough. Mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: The toolbar has formatting options, the brackets are the fifth from the left.

Comment: @StevenLiao Thank you Steven, I will surely look into that. I'm just so much used to using (select-all) then the tab key with my Notepad++ then pasting into afterwards, all in one shot.

Comment: Your code does not work. You define a function that gets never called, then you put an SQL query string into a variable, and you call a method `execute` on something that might be an object or not, with a lot of data? Is this code actually supposed to work in this way?

Comment: sorry, no it's not actually meant to work, its just how would I put $st->execute as part of the $values?

Comment: Re-edited it so it is a bit clearer for people.

Comment: You can't use that `$values` string in the query. You need to make an array of it, and you can then pass that array directly to `execute()` instead of wrapping it into another array.

Comment: @Sven Sorry I am not entirely sure what you mean? so $values = "array(':username' => $_POST['username'], ':password' => $_POST['password1'], ':email' => $_POST['email'], ':county' => $_POST['county'])" and at the top $st->execute($values)?

Comment: Still syntax errors with that way

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Function name must be a string and PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: dbcon :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

function doQuery($db, $query, $arguments) {
    //Prepare and execute SQL         
    $st = $db->prepare($query);       
    $st->execute(array($values));
    return $st;
    // it makes no sense to echo PHP errors manually, hence no try catch needed
}

// 1. Don't create the database inside of the same function that does the queries,
//    creation/destruction of the objects/connections will cause unnecessary overhead,
$myDb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'dbuser', 'dbpassword');
$myDb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); //Set error mode

$myQuery = "INSERT INTO users(login,pass,email,county) VALUES(:username,:password,:email,:count)";

// 2. You can't define an array like that.
// 3. You do not need to add colons to the array indexes.
$myValues = array(
    'username' => $_POST['username'],
    'password' => $_POST['password1'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'county' => $_POST['county']
);

doquery($myDb, $myQuery, $myValues);
// having a single db handle lets you to get the insert id
$id = $myDb->insertId();
// Returning the statement allows to use this function with SELECT queries as well:
$row = doquery($myDb, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?", [$id])->fetch();
```

Comment: Hi Sammitch, it does look good but do you recommend not using a function at all then? My main reason for it is because I would like a way to reduce code for something I would be using quite often.

Comment: @user2784248 using a function isn't a bad thing itself, I would just not recommend initializing the database in the same function that does the queries. Give me a second to re-jigger my answer.

Comment: Thanks, as I already have working code. I am just trying to make it as efficient as possible and presumably I will be using the $db->prepare and execute a good few times. Though I didn't think of the overhead by talking to mysql all the time. So thanks for explaining a bit of that, any further explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to include " : " in your parameters array ?

```
/*Function to talk to database*/
function doQuery($myDB, $myQuery, $myValues)
{
    try
    {     
        $st = $myDB->prepare($myQuery);       
        $st->execute(array($myValues));
        //echo $success;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Failed because: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='dbanme';charset=utf8', 'dbuser', 'dbpass');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); //Set error mode
    $query = "INSERT INTO users(login,pass,email,county) VALUES(:username,:password,:email,:count)";
    $values = array(':username' => $_POST['username'],
                     ':password' => $_POST['password1'],
                     ':email' => $_POST['email'],
                     ':county' => $_POST['county']
                     );
    doQuery($db, $query, $values);
```

I hope this worked!